# Bootstrap 4.0 w-lg-1000

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola Buenas Noches como variar el ancho de un div dependiendo del dispositivo :

uso :  w-lg-80  w-md-60  w-sm-100 pero no funciona.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="container w-lg-60">

<div class="row" style="background-color:#C2F8F7">



<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid">


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<b>Registro de Clientes</b> 
</div>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<img src="img/registro_cliente.png">    
</div>
```

Comment: De dónde has sacado estas clases? `w-lg-60`, `w-md-60`..... si no la has creado tu no te va a funcionar

Comment: Como te indica el compañero @aldanux, te estás inventando unas clases que Bootstrap no define. Siendo exactos parece que estás mezclando 2 maneras de definir el tamaño de un elemento. No existe la clase **w-lg-80** puedes usar la clase **w-75** ya que si usas estas clases para definir tamaño no puedes indicar a que tamaño de dispositivo quieres que se aplique, tampoco puedes definir el número que se te antoje. (puedes usar las medidas 25, 50, 75 y 100). Si lo que necesitas es en cambio definir el tamaño del elemento dependiendo del dispositivo tienes que usar el grid de Bootstrap (col-md-6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para variar dependiendo del dispositivo tendrías que crear las columnas con `.col-sm/md/lg/xl` ya que las clases `.w-25/50/75/100` lo unico que hacen es definir que el elemento va a tener en **cualquier** tipo de dispositivo un ancho de **25% / 50% / 75% / 100%**.

> ¿En qué se diferencian las medidas de las columnas?

`.col-` esta clase sirve para dispositivos que tienen una pantalla con menos de 576px de ancho.

`.col-sm` esta sirve para los dispositivos con pantallas de 576 o o más px de ancho

`.col-md` esta sirve para los dispositivos con pantallas de 768 o más px de ancho

`.col-lg` sirve para los dispositivos con pantallas de 992 o más px de ancho

`.col-xl` sirve para los dispositivos con pantallas de 1200 o más px de ancho

> ¿Cómo funciona el `grid system` de Bootstrap?

El sistema de cuadrículas de Bootstrap  se puede dividir en **12** columnas por línea (`.row`).

Un ejemplo de su funcionamiento:

```css
span {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1"> <p> 1 </p> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"> <p> 2 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"> <p> 2 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"> <p> 2 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"> <p> 2 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"> <p> 2 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"> <p> 2 </p> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"> <p> 3 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"> <p> 3 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"> <p> 3 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"> <p> 3 </p> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"> <p> 4 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"> <p> 4 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"> <p> 4 </p> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"> <p> 6 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"> <p> 6 </p> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"> <p> 12 </p> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como podes observar cada `.row` contiene a su interno columnas que suman un valor de **12** en este caso usé siempre las mismas "medidas" para mostrarte el funcionamiento, pero podría funcionar también así :

**Para ver la diferencia usa el botón 'pantalla completa' y juega con la dimensión del *browser***

```css
p {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"> <p> 3 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6"> <p> 6 </p> </span>
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"> <p> 3 </p> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-7 col-xl-5"> <p> &nbsp; </p> </span>
    <span class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-5"> <p> &nbsp; </p> </span>
    <span class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"> <p> &nbsp; </p> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Como ves, la suma de las columnas **siempre** es **12**

Espero que te sea de ayuda para comprender cómo tendrías que hacer para solucionar tu problema.

**PD: las columnas no siempre tienen que tener el mismo valor por cada dispositivo, es decir, podrías también hacer algo por el estilo : `<div class='col-sm-3 col-lg-6'> </div>` con esto, la medida del elemento cambia en base al dispositivo**

Éxitos.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo usa media querys segun el tamaño del dispositivo asignale los damaños que desees a los divs, es la mejor opcion y totalmente responsiva.

```html
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```